# What are the limit points of the sequence ${(-1)^n+\frac{2}{n}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I know that 1 and -1 are the limit points. But how do i prove these are the only ones (If they are, but i am pretty sure they are) Do i have to show that every sequence made from the set only converge to these numbers? How would i do that?

Comment: You could try this approach: Pick any $x$ other than $1$ and $-1$. Find a small positive $\epsilon$ and a large natural number $N$ such the interval $(x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon)$ contains no element of your sequence whenever $n \geq N$. You would be showing that eventually your sequence is "far" away from any $x$ other than $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: So should i divide the set into two pieces. For odd and even $n$. Then say $x \in A$. Since $x \in A$, say it is in the set ${1+\frac{1}{k}}$ HEnce there is $k_0$ for which $x=1+\frac{1}{k_0}$ Now the next closest item in the set would be $1+\frac{1}{k_0+1}$. So now we take $\epsilon<\frac{1}{k_0}-\frac{1}{k_0+1}$. End?

Comment: the even steps subsequence is $1+\frac{1}{n}$ which converges to $1$

Comment: @janmarqz And for odd the sequence is $-1+\frac{2}{2k+1}$, which converges to -1. Sure but i have to show that any combination of the elements of the set do not converge to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the quantity $x_n - x_m$, where $x_j = (-1)^j + \frac{2}{j}$.

It is equal to $(-1)^n- (-1)^m + \frac{2}{n} - \frac{2}{m}$.

Any convergent sequence is Cauchy, so we want to see what kind of subsequences of $x_n$ can possibly be Cauchy.

Note that $\frac{2}{n} - \frac{2}{m}$ would go to zero anyway, so it doesn't affect the Cauchy property of any sequence. On the other hand, $$
|(-1)^n - (-1)^m| = \begin{cases}
0 & n - m \text{ even}\\
1 & n - m \text{ odd}
\end{cases}
$$ 
Hence, we want $n$ and $m$ to eventually have the same parity, in order to give convergence,  otherwise it will not happen.

> Hence a subsequence $\{ x_{n_k}\}$ of $x_n$ is convergent if and only if $n_k$ eventually has the same parity (even/odd).

Now, it is easy to see  that if $n_k$ has odd parity, then $(-1)^n = -1$, so the sequence $x_{n_k}$ converges to $-1$.

Similarly, it is easy to see  that if $n_k$ has even parity, then $(-1)^n = 1$, so the sequence $x_{n_k}$ converges to $1$.

Hence, the only other limit points are $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: Thank you, i feel it is a bit shaky when it comes to ignoring the $2/m$ and $2/n$ but i know why you can do that using intuition.

Comment: @Sorfosh You are welcome. There is no question of intuition here, it is simply to note that $\frac{2}{n}-\frac{2}{m}$ goes to zero as $n,m$ increase, so the factor does not affect any sequence's properties in the long run on addition.